# Project Euler #7 Python wrong output

Tags: python

I wrote below code in Python and i want to find 10001st prime number. I get 103903 as answer but the correct answer is 104743. What am i doing wrong?

```
def primes(n):

    primes = [2]
    i = 3

    while len (primes) < n:
        if isprime(i):
            primes.append(i)
        i = i + 1

    return primes [-1]

def isprime(n):
    i = 2
    if ((i ** n) - i) % n == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Show your `isprime` function. Also, no need to store all the primes, just remember the last one.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Please make sure that others are able to run it. Also, questions like "what am I doing wrong" will usually not lead to getting good answers. Try to be more specific. What have you tried? What are you expecting the outcome to be, etc.?

Comment: I updated my post, you can see isprime function. @tobias_k

Comment: Ehrm... where did you get that `isprime` function from? That's not right. It seems like this is just a _heuristic_ test, i.e. it works in some, maybe even most cases, but not always.

Comment: I used Fermat's little theorem on Wikipedia @tobias_k

Comment: What are you passing as `n` in the `primes` function? 10001 right?

Comment: Also you really don't need a list. Try replacing the list with a `count` variable and increment `count` by one instead of appending to the list. That'll be the same as `len(primes)`.

Comment: I have changed it and used a counter. It works faster than keeping a list. Thank you.
@FurkanKambay

Answer (score 0):

Your `isprime` function is not correct. While it *does* work for many cases, and indeed produces the correct result for all numbers up to around 300, it still is just a heuristic. It seems like you took that function from [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) but note that the theorem says that *if* p is a prime, then this holds for *all* numbers a, so you can't just check whether it holds for a=2 and then decide that p is a prime.

From the Wikipedia page on [Primality Tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Fermat_primality_test) on the Fermat primality test:

> Given an integer n, choose some integer a coprime to n and calculate a^(n-1) % n. If the result is different from 1, then n is composite. If it is 1, then n **may** be prime.

For a proper `isprime` function, there's no way around trial-dividing by all the potential divisors. If that's too slow for the Project Euler problem, there are a few things you can optimize, e.g. only test divisors up to `sqrt(n)`, and only if those have previously been identified as being prime.

Comment: Yes you are right, i have changed my primality test, i used a counter instead of keeping a list and it worked properly.

Comment: @BahadirBozatli In fact, keep the list. You can use the already identified prime numbers from the list to speed up the `isprime` check.